# Power Apps - Get info from view form to be copied to an edit form on another screen

Tags: powerapps, editform

I am trying to get the info on a view form to be displayed on an edit form that is on another screen. The view form has its data from several galleries on other screens. The galleries are all from the same datasource but some of them are filtered which is why I created variables to display on the view screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you are using variables that are displayed in a View form, why not use the same variables as the Default values for the input controls of the Edit form?